# Changing the warning level with Qt Creator and MinGW

Tags: mingw, qt-creator

I'm trying to find a way to change the warning level (I believe the default is 3 and I'd like to change it to 4) of my project developped using Qt Creator (1.3.0) and MinGW.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the qmake manual.

I also have Qt Creator 1.3.0 and MinGW and notice that the
     `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON`
variable appears to be set to -Wall.  There are a number of QMAKE_CXXFLAGS... variables.  These can be set/changed/adjusted in your *.pro file.

E.g. in myproject.pro

```
win32:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wextra
```

Comment: Thanks ! For the record, here are the flags I've set :

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wconversion –Wsign-conversion

And here is the flag I sometimes add to have warnings considered errors :

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wconversion –Wsign-conversion -Werror

Comment: @dave c thank you for your answer, in the example you provided for the .pro file, there is possibly a typo, there shouldnt be an underscore between cxx and flags. Correct one should be
"win32:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wextra"